# GridView EmptyDataTemplate

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET GridView that uses an EmptyDataTemplate. This template is used to collect data in the event that no records exist in my data source. My GridView source looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="Lecturer" CellPadding="4"
ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" style="text-align: center" allowsorting="True">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="URL" SortExpression="url" DataNavigateUrlFields="url" Text="Link"  ItemStyle-Width="100" />  
</Columns>

<EmptyDataTemplate>
    No data found!
</EmptyDataTemplate>

<EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
```

The problem here is that i want the empty data template to be shown after the button search has been click but right now everytime i open the page, it will show the empty data template eventhough i didnt do any searching yet.

Comment: If you want a message to be shown when search result is empty then you'll have to do it manually, `EmptyDataTemplate` isn't meant for this, `EmptyDataTemplate` will be shown whenever grid doesn't have any record.

Answer (score 11):

use:
 `EmptyDataText="No data found!"`
in a grid like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" EmptyDataText="No data found!" ....>
```

Your way is incorrect.`EmptyDataTemplate` isn't use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `EmptyDataTemplate`, when you search if no records match with the search, set `EmptyDataText` of your gridview.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are binding your GridView in your Page_Load event instead of the Search button click.  Move your binding code into a separate method and call that method when the search button is clicked in its click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private DataTable GetDataTable(Boolean blnIsReturnNull)
{
        DataTable tblReturnTable = new DataTable();
        tblReturnTable.Columns.Add("name");
        tblReturnTable.Columns.Add("URL");
        if (blnIsReturnNull)
        {
            return tblReturnTable;
        }
        for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 10; intCounter++)
        {
            //Build of tblReturnTable
        }
        return tblReturnTable;
}

 protected void cmdEmptyGridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable(true);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


<asp:Button ID="cmdEmptyGridView" runat="server" Text="Empty GridView" OnClick="cmdEmptyGridView_Click"
                            CssClass="Button" /></td>
```